# Python 3.8.6 openpyxl.load_workbook('Config/Test_Sheet2.xlsx') is giving error File is not a zip file

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
try:
    WB = openpyxl.load_workbook('Config/Test_Sheet2.xlsx')
    WB.save(self.filename)
    WB.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Above code is giving exception as "File not a zip file". How to fix this problem?

Comment: I have openpyxl 3.0.5 and Microsoft excel 2013

Comment: The file obviously isn't what you think it is. All XLSX files must be zip files.